# Typelite for dummies

Tags: typescript, web-essentials, typelite

Could someone please tell me what exactly there is supposed to be in my Scripts\TypeLite.tt file when my class is defined in my Default.aspx.cs file like this:

```
namespace typelite 
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       { 

       }

       public class Address
       {
           public string Street { get; set; }
       }
    }
}
```

I cannot get the tutorial to work. (Typelite is a tool to get Typescript definitions from c# classes. I am using the Nuget )
It is the method that does not use ForLoadedAssemblies() I am interested in:
http://type.litesolutions.net/Tutorials. I read the tutorial and I tried downloading the stable version and neither works.

EDIT:
Use Web essentials for this! Visual studio 2013 installed with web essentials 2013 - right-click a .cs file and select "Web Essentials -> Create Typescript intellisense file" and voila :)

Comment: Perhaps try reading the [TypeLITE tutorial](http://type.litesolutions.net/Tutorials)?

Comment: @RoadieRich editing post - I can't get the tutorial to work. (My post is using the example from the tutorial)

Comment: [There's an example typelite.tt file in the demo folder of the source repo.](https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/src/a0c8ec0b3346091b76e1fcfe379a56a0432a9b41/TypeLite.Demo/Scripts/TypeLite.tt?at=default)

Comment: Just downloaded the stable version from https://bitbucket.org/LukasKabrt/typelite/downloads deleted contents of TypeLite.d.ts, right clicked the TypeLite.tt and chose 'run custom tool'. Result was 'ErrorGeneratingOutput' in TypeLite.d.ts Very strange

Comment: @DNRN Web Essentials have this functionality now - see the Edit I just added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the dll is present at the right location for tt to work. Installing via nugget and then building your project would do this for you.

Comment: I am going nuts - I just created new project, 'ASP.NET Web Forms Application', add TypeLite Nuget and immediately get TypeLite.dll not  found error.

Comment: it should show you where it was not found. Try copying the dll to that location manually

Comment: Very strange - now it is working. I used the forloaded assemblies. Should I removed typelite before production or does it not matter?

Comment: If your code is in the tt file it will not run unless you manually do it from vs. Leave it in there.